# How to design a simple role based access control with Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose in my nodejs application, I have two Models: an Employee and Organization , I want to attribute some permissions to employees who belong to an organization like  inviting or deleting  other employees

I've created a mdoel ACL(_id,_empId,_orgId,[permissions]), but I'm not sure if will do the trick

What Models do I have to add in my database, knowing that I need just few permissions

Comment: what have you tried?, this problem can be solved with just basic role/permission models , one specific role can be assigned to the users `managers` with the special permissions, that can invite/delete other users from an organization , its pretty simple is you look at it that way..

Comment: Ok , is  permission  a Model or just  enumerated type ?

Comment: yes it should be a model , because should be able to add/remove anytime , take a ready package for example https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl